# Constructor Overload Hide Properties in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, formatting, constructor-overloading

I have a class that has two different constructors, and it has 4 properties. For our purposes, it looks something like the following:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public int PubDate { get; set; }
 
    public Book(string title, string author)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
    }
 
    public Book(string title, string author, string publisher, int pubDate)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
        Publisher = publisher;
        PubDate = pubDate;
    }
}
```

When the user passes in only two parameters, the first constructor should technically create the object.

The problem I'm having is that I want to display that object in PowerShell with whatever parameter was used to instantiate it, for example a Book instantiated using only Title and Author, should display Book's Title and Author only in terminal.

I was looking at using [format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1) to format this.

Comment: Create a private flag that tracks which constructor was used.  If I remember correctly, there's a way for the object to decide what properties are exposed (at runtime) to the output pipeline

Comment: Is the data types in your project set in stone (eg. this is what a `Book` class looks like and you won't be able to change that)? If so, your best bet is to modify the `pstypenames` property immediately after creation. Otherwise, split into two separate classes, a `Book` with just author + title, and a `PublishedBook` the derives from `Book` and adds the publication info